# Как, по-вашему, лучше и быстрее выучить русскую грамматику и начать писать грамотно?

Tags: грамматика, обучение

Как, по-вашему, лучше и быстрее выучить русскую грамматику и начать писать грамотно?

PS. Сделал тренажёр по улучшению грамотности письма, если у кого есть желание помочь с развитием, буду рад.

Comment: Вопрос —— Почему решил сделать?

Comment: Хотелось бы услышать: справедливую критику, замечания, пожелания и оценки.

Comment: Оценка одна. Спам, реклама, подлежит удалению.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что  СПАМ

Comment: Этот "вопрос" в лучшем случае выглядит как ответ на незаданный вопрос.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, как проверять слово. Предлагается исправить несуществующие ошибки, где пропущена! а не допущена ошибка! Напр: в...долаз. Где здесь ошибка? К тому же, когда вставляешь букву и нажимаешь ''проверить'' ответ приходит неверный. Или я недопонял что-то, или тренажер плохо работает.

Comment: В рекламе меня еще можно обвинить, но я не спамер. Вот смотрите, некоторое время назад я решил начать заниматься самообразованием, начал учить программирование, а потом понял что грамматику подтянуть было бы тоже хорошо и пришла идея написать вот такой ресурс, сделал, но хотелось бы обратной связи от людей которые в данном вопросе понимают больше чем я и решил написать тут.

Comment: Удалил ссылку, так как обвинили меня во всех смертных грехах, да и смысла обсуждать не вижу так как изначально все настроены негативно. Серж, а про ваш пример, вы возможно даже сообщение о ошибке не прочитали и там была просто ошибка в капче, ее поставил для того что бы без регистрации не абузили чекер.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрела одну тему в тренажере (гласные после шипящих), она меня несколько  удивила. Конечно, надо вчитываться подробнее, но общее впечатление неблагоприятное. Сделана попытка обобщения (что хорошо), но неудачная и по содержанию, и по непонятному и тяжеловесному языку.

Например:

"КОРЕНЬ. В любой части речи1) пишется ё, если при изменении слова или подборе родственных слов гласная е оказывается в сильной позиции (под ударением) или в безударном положении в корне употребляется е:Шёпот-шéпчет-шептáть".

Попробуем воспользоваться инструкцией. Чем отличается два варианта с разным написанием: жёлтый – желтеть, шок – шокировать? В обоих случаях в однокоренных словах  в ударной позиции Е не встречается, а безударный звук надо проверять (там слышится редуцированный гласный).  Слова шоколад, шоссе, шовинизм  к этой орфограмме вообще не имеют отношения, это непроверяемые безударные гласные (контроль по словарю).

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

"Как по вашему лучше и быстрее выучить русскую грамматику и начать писать грамотно?"

1) Грамматику учить не надо, надо ЗНАТЬ определенный грамматический минимум. Все правила основаны на грамматике, их надо не учить, а понимать, из чего они следуют.

3) Буквы надо не писать, а следует обозначать ими звуки. Писать текст нужно по слуху, но с учетом фонетического чередования, то есть проверяя звуки в слабых позициях

3)  Надо хорошо понимать основные принципы орфографии и пунктуации и ПРИМЕНЯТЬ ИХ НА ПРАКТИКЕ.

4)Надо различать орфограммы графические (жёлтеть - выбираем букву для известного звука) и фонетические (гора - проверяем звук, а потом вбираем для него букву).

И т.д.

Comment: Что не так? В случае если у нас есть слово где Е находится в корне слова и под ударением - пишется Ё. Ваш пример - Жёлтый-желтеет-желтеть - подходит под это правило. Вот если у меня допустим сомнение писать жёлтый или жолтый, но если взять воспользовавшись орфограммой становится понятно, что надо писать жёлтый, так как вы же не напишите жолтеет или жолтеть. Слова шоколад, шоссе, шовинизм - иностранного происхождения и в них отсутствует такое звуковое чередование, пишем о. У вас есть примеры которые противоречат этому утверждению?

Comment: PS правила я не сам писал и не редактировал, а брал и основывался на курсе подготовки к экзаменам от МГУ.

Comment: Жёлтый - подходит, а шокировать - не подходит.  Если чередование Е/Ё отсутствует, то можно написать любую букву в позиции редуцированного звука, а не только О: жалеть, жилет, жокей, жираф, железо.  Тема эта сложная, мало кому до конца понятная и поэтому требует не машинного (с алгоритмами) , а ручного управления. Ваше правило ничего не добавляет к обычным формулировкам, но  читается с трудом и не во всем корректно.  И непонятно, что вообще дает ваш тренажер, если в нем используются заимствованные правила.

Comment: 1. Употребление гласных !!О/Е!! после шипящих. Из вашего списка к правило относится только жокей который полностью попадает под правило. 2. Тренажёр (от англ. train — воспитывать, обучать, тренировать) — механическое, электрическое либо комбинированное учебно-тренировочное устройство, искусственно имитирующее различные нагрузки или обстоятельства (ситуацию). Тренажёры могут быть обучающими (имитационными) или спортивными. И при чем тут чужие правила к моим упражнениям?

Comment: Вы хорошо понимаете связь букв О/Ё/Е (не только после шипящих, а вообще) , чем она обусловлена исторически, как проявляется в настоящее время?

Comment: Так я с вами не хочу вступать в спор или что-то подобное, так как вероятно знаний и опыта по этому вопросу у меня меньше. Но вот тут: http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=17#pp17, все то же написано и про иностранные слова там тоже есть.

Comment: Если у вас есть вариант где это все объясняется лучше и лаконичней, пожалуйста дайте мне его, так как те правила которые сейчас на сайте - это лучшие варианты подачи материала которые мной были найдены(мое мнение).

Comment: Я вам могу предложить такую формулировку:    1. При выборе О/Ё  после шипящих и Ц ПОД УДАРЕНИЕМ гласная второго ряда  Ё пишется в ДВУХ СЛУЧАЯХ: во-первых, в корне слов с чередованием Е/Ё: шёпот – шептать, щёки – щека.во-вторых,   в суффиксах и окончаниях глаголов и глагольных форм: бережёт, печёный, освещённый. 
   2. В остальных случаях ПОД УДАРЕНИЕМ пишется гласная первого ряда О, а именно:  
А) в корнях без чередования Е/Ё (шорох, шов),
Б) в суффиксах и окончаниях существительных, прилагательных и наречий (снежок, горячо),В)  а также во всех случаях после Ц (цокот, танцор, перцовый).

Comment: Всегда удобнее четко обозначить написания одного варианта, а другой вариант считать остальным. И еще словарик добавить с редкими словами, чтобы разделить основное (99% ) от частного (1%).

Comment: В общем, с вами согласен, форма подачи материала не всегда хороша и рассмотренный вами пример стоит переработать. Просто дело в том что тренажер построен по плану обучения и О.Е после Ц рассмотрено в следующем разделе. А совмещать разделы я не хочу. Ваш вариант - хороший и я подумаю над ним.

Comment: Шипящие и Ц - единая группа с одинаковым характером, так как когда-то все они были мягкие и сохранили "мягкие привычки" до сих пор (это, прежде всего,   редукция гласных  по мягкому варианту, отсюда следует единое правило О/Е после шипящих и Ц). Поэтому не стоит считать их совсем разными темами.